# Where are my previously bookmarked questions

Tags: support, bookmarks

This seems like such a stupid question. Ugh! but I suddenly cant -- not even to save my own life -- find the list of questions I bookmarked in the past.  I bookmarked them by clicking the star below the vote up/down buttons.  Would someone please remind me where I can access my list of bookmarked questions???

Comment: This probably has something to do with it: https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/10/04/meet-saves-the-tool-to-help-you-organize-your-favorite-content-on-stack-overflow/?cb=1&_ga=2.220613976.1306756629.1664771917-1535139383.1468957898

Comment: There is a discussion about that on Meta stack [exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/1195193)